# Why clones instead of droids in Republic?

Tags: star-wars

So in the newer trilogy the separatists use droids while the Grand Army of the Republic is primarily composed of clones. It seems like it is a huge waste of human life to be use them(despite the fact they are clones) instead of droids for fighting a war. Is there an actual reason they don't have their own droids when the technology is clearly known?

Comment: Droids are so last millennia and everyone has one now. Clones are the future.

Comment: Remember when that little kid blew up a spaceship and basically ended a war immediately?

Answer (score 5):

Prime Minister Lama Su gives a pretty good insight into why Clones are preferable to droids

> **LAMA SU:** *They're immensely superior to droids, capable of independent thought and action.*

As you can see throughout the shows, the clones are capable of cutting down *dozens* of droids for every clone casualty. Even when backed up by superior numbers, the droid armies are persistently pushed back by the Clone armies.

---

Speaking to the question of why the Republic doesn't have a large, standing droid army, the answer is that they rely on the Jedi to keep peace and order, something they've accomplished handily for a thousand generations. It's only in the few years of the Republic's existence that an army was *suddenly* needed. I think we can be reasonably sure that if the Kaminoans had offered a million-strong *droid* army, the Republic would have accepted that just as readily.

Comment: And remember that the entire Clone Wars conflict was rigged by a particular individual who was playing both sides.  The goal all along was for the Republic to win, so it makes sense for the new Republic army to have the superior force.  And that individual hardly cares about preservation of life...

Comment: @Brandon - I have seen that through the shows, and that's the biggest problem I have with them. The ability to have "independent thought and action" matters mostly on a tactical level, while down in direct combat the higher processing speeds of computers (along with droids being made of metal with is tougher than flesh)really should have made any living being be outclassed by droids. And if you tell me it's because the CIS built only the cheapest stuff, I tell you that even then the AI should be well developed (one-time investment) and even cheap CPU are faster than humans in thought.

Comment: @AnjuMaaka - They're easily knocked down by the Gungans. It's probably easier to think of them as mobile gun carriers

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, that's kinda the problem. If you're going to make billions of those super-cheap droids you would STILL invest at least in the AI because you make that one time and then can give it to every single droid without any further costs. So I feel it's WRONG that they appear so incompetent; it would be fine if the issue was that they were slow, or easily destroyed, but they should have at least a decent targeting AI in them!!

Answer (score 1):

My theory involves Order 66. A dead clone would leave no evidence of the plot that was to unfold; however, a damaged droid would be a liability leaving evidence behind for anyone clever enough to go through the droid's programming. Also, I don't believe the higher level Jedi would have trusted droids enough to be caught off guard.

Answer (score 0):

It Episode II: Attack of the Clones the "selling point" is that clones are much more adaptable than driods.

The idea for a clone army was originally due to the Jedi Master [Sifo-Dyas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sifo-Dyas), though the Sith found out about it and took it over. Presumably, it was also part of  Darth Sidious's machinations for Dooku and friends to make use of droids, while the Empire made use of clones?